# Button is not showing up when jquery sortable list is changed

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using the jquery sortable functionality, and I have a list that is sortable, Now I want the save sorted order button to show up if the user change the sorting order otherwise that button should not be displayed. I have written my own function showButton and calling it in update attribute of jquery sortable function but it is not working. Below is my code:

```
    <script>      
    $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
            $('#sorted_order').val(order.join(","));
           showButton();

        }
});
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});

function showButton()
{   

 var field = "#somefield_id";//is the field after which I want my button to show up

 $node = '<input type="submit" id="saveBtn" value="save Order">';

 $(field).after($node); 

};
```

Please suggest if there is any other good way to to this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want the user to be able to see the button when they have *finished* sorting. In this case, use 'stop'.
e.g.:

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        cursor: 'crosshair',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var order = $("#sortable").sortable("toArray");
            $('#sorted_order').val(order.join(","));
        },
        stop: function() {
            showButton();
        }
});
```

Read more in the api for [stop](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop).